# How can i rotate an image over its x axes in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to rotate an image over its x axes but its not working

```
Texture one = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img/one.jpg"));
oneImg = new Image(one);
oneImg.setOrigin(oneImg.getWidth() / 2, oneImg.getHeight() / 2);
oneImg.setPosition(stage.getWidth() / 2-32 , stage.getHeight()/2);
oneImg.setScale(2f,2f);
oneImg.addAction(rotateBy(360, 0.5f));
```

Comment: In 2d, you can simulate x-axis rotation by scaling in y direction from 1 to -1 and back using the correct (sinus) interpolation

Comment: can you please show me a simple code implementation of that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate your texture right when you draw it on the batch.

```
SpriteBatch.draw(textureRegion.getTexture(), x, y, originX, originY, width, height, scaleX, scaleY, rotation, srcX, srcX, srcWidth, srcHeight, false, false);
```

So above is the exact code that you need to rotate your image in x-axis, y-axis or both.

where :

```
x - the x-coordinate in screen space
y - the y-coordinate in screen space

originX - the x-coordinate of the scaling and rotation origin relative to the screen space coordinates
originY - the y-coordinate of the scaling and rotation origin relative to the screen space coordinates

width - the width in pixels
height - the height in pixels

scaleX - the scale of the rectangle around originX/originY in x
scaleY - the scale of the rectangle around originX/originY in y

rotation - the angle of counter clockwise rotation of the rectangle around originX/originY

srcX - the x-coordinate in texel space
srcY - the y-coordinate in texel space

srcWidth - the source with in texels
srcHeight - the source height in texels
```